# pytest for django rest frame work api returns 301

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I made simple Django application which returns {'result': 'OK'} for endpoint '/api/v1/test/ping/'. Now I am trying to test it with pytest.

My test directory

```
/test
   conftest.py
   /test_app
       test_api.py
```

My conftest.py

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient
```

My test_api.py

```
import pytest


def test_api1(api_client):
    response = api_client().get("/api/v1/test/ping")

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Test script execution fails:

```
test_api.py::test_api1 FAILED                                            [100%]
test\test_gml_api\test_api.py:3 (test_api1)
301 != 200
```

But code works correct if I run server and check it manually! Give me please an advise how to solve this?

Comment: Try with a trailing slash: `.get("/api/v1/test/ping/")`?